# Is it safe to use macros I created in Google's web apps?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-macro

I recorded a macro in Google Sheets, which can be done by going to Tools > Macros. However, when I try to run it, I am asked for permission to for it to be run.

I get the following messages:

> **Authorization Required**
>
> A script attached to this document needs your permission to run.

After I select "Continue," I am asked to:

> **Choose an account** to continue to Recorded Macros (Tasks)

After selecting my account, I am met with the message

> **Recorded Macros (Tasks) wants to access your Google Account**
>
> **This will allow Recorded Macros (Tasks) to:**
>
> View and manage spreadsheets that this application has been installed in
>
> **Make sure you trust Recorded Macros (Tasks)**
>
> You may be sharing sensitive info with this site or app. Learn about how Recorded Macros (Tasks) will handle your data by reviewing its terms of service and privacy policies. You can always see or remove access in your Google Account.
>
> [Learn about the risks](https://support.google.com/accounts?p=oauth_consent)
>
> **[Cancel] [Allow]**

This seems to be similar to the messages faced when trying to link a third-party app you Google account, and as I mentioned it seemed like these macros is a first-party feature. However, the number of authorizations Google is asking makes it seem like it isn't.

So is it safe to run these macros, which I personally created, on my Google sheets document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the macro is created by you then it is totally safe. The warning is general eg. it doesn't differentiate if the macro was created by you or by someone else. The whole procedure is just safety protocol designed to give a user "more control" over possibly malicious (in case you run unknown macro) action. Same happens when you try to add a custom script to your spreadsheet.